# How to properly set totalSeconds() (hours minutes seconds) in my line of code and return it

Tags: java, methods, constructor, getter-setter

Hey guys my teacher gave me a clock program to make, it has to return information etc, so far I'm a little confused on how total seconds is supposed to work, I will show my driver and normal file below, please help. I have to make sure the Hours Minutes and Seconds return in total seconds. I will post live edits I make to my code

I have tried to return it by adding a variable and adding it in the driver to no avail.

```
{

  //Instance Variables
  private int Hours;
  private int Minutes;
  private int Seconds;
  private double Cost;
  private boolean IsOn;
  private int DLS;



  //Zero arg constructors
  public Clock()
  { // Start
    Hours = 10;
    Minutes = 52;
    Seconds = 23;   
    Cost = 20.00;
    IsOn = true;
    DLS = 11;
  } // End

  //Multi-Argument Constructors

  public Clock( int Hours, int Minutes, int Seconds, double Cost , boolean IsOn, int DSL)
  { // Start
    this.Hours = Hours;
    this.Minutes = Minutes;
    this.Seconds = Seconds;
    this.Cost = Cost;
    this.IsOn = IsOn;
    this.DLS = DLS;
  } // End

  public void setTime(int Hours)
  {
    System.out.println(Hours + 1);
  }

  public int convertDaylightSaving(int Hours)
  {
    return Hours;
  }



  //ToString Method

  public String toString()
  { //Start
    String output;
    output = "When I checked my watch the hour was: " + Hours + "\n" + 
      "When I checked my watch the minute was: " + Minutes + "\n" +
      "When I checked my watch the seconds were: " + Seconds + "\n" +
      "The Cost is: " + Cost + "\n" +
      "Is this the time right now?: " + IsOn;

    return output;

  }
} // End
```

```
public class ClockDriver
{ 
 public class ClockDriver
{ // Start

  public static void main(String[] args)
  { // Officially Start

    Clock Watch = new Clock( 11, 04, 16, 35.99, false, 11);
    System.out.println(Watch);
  } // End
} // Officially End
```

The expected results are for it to print out everything I've made, the result is that it errors.

Comment: Your code will not function until you fix the compilation issues. For example, `this.Time = Time;` - you have no `Time`. Also, `public void setTime(int Hours, Minutes, Seconds)` `Minutes` and `Seconds` have no type. And, `public int convertDaylightSaving(int Hours + 1)` isn't legal either. Basically, your posted code needs significant remediation.

Comment: I fixed it all thank you, it compiles, I just don't know where to get started on the convert to seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I actually answered my own question by doing the following.

```
public class Clock
{

  //Instance Variables
  private int Hours;
  private int Minutes;
  private int Seconds;
  private double Cost;
  private boolean IsOn;
  private int DLS;
  int totalSeconds; 



  //Zero arg constructors
  public Clock()
  { // Start
    Hours = 10;
    Minutes = 52;
    Seconds = 23;   
    Cost = 20.00;
    IsOn = true;
    DLS = 11;
    totalSeconds = 9945;
  } // End

  //Multi-Argument Constructors

  public Clock( int Hours, int Minutes, int Seconds, double Cost , boolean IsOn, int DSL, int totalSeconds)
  { // Start
    this.Hours = Hours;
    this.Minutes = Minutes;
    this.Seconds = Seconds;
    this.Cost = Cost;
    this.IsOn = IsOn;
    this.DLS = DLS;
    this.totalSeconds = totalSeconds;
  } // End

  public void setTime(int Hours)
  {
    System.out.println(Hours + 1);
  }

  public int convertDaylightSaving(int Hours)
  {
    return Hours;
  }
    public int totalSeconds()
    {
      return totalSeconds + 5000;
    }


  //ToString Method

  public String toString()
  { //Start
    String output;
    output = "When I checked my watch the hour was: " + Hours + "\n" + 
      "When I checked my watch the minute was: " + Minutes + "\n" +
      "When I checked my watch the seconds were: " + Seconds + "\n" +
      "The Cost is: " + Cost + "\n" +
      "Is this the time right now?: " + IsOn + "\n" + 
      "The total seconds right now are: " + totalSeconds;


    return output;

  }
} // End
```

After that I made the driver and had it return

```
public class ClockDriver
{ // Start

  public static void main(String[] args)
  { // Officially Start

    Clock Watch = new Clock( 11, 04, 16, 35.99, false, 11, 9945);
    System.out.println(Watch);
}
  } // End
```

Comment: This code is VERY VERY chaotic if you're doing this for homework I would not advise copying and pasting, there are so many loose ends that'll make your teacher raise an eyebrow